# undefined method admin Thredded Forum engine Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im using a forum engine called Thredded. The installation goes well but when trying to access localhost:3000/forum , it gives me this error.
[image]

I already trying the suggested solution by adding a method admin? on user.rb but still it doesnt work.

```
def admin?
  has_role?(:admin)
end
```

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the missing method is `admin`, not `admin?`. Try defining that method instead:

```
def admin
  has_role?(:admin)
end
```

Comment: hi, it seems working.. thanks.. but i had to comment has_role?(:admin) cuz i  still needed to configure the roles of my users...  are you familiar of the Forum engine called thredded?

Comment: I'm not familiar with thredded, sorry.

Comment: For someone who doesn't know where did `has_role?` method come from, [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem provides this method.

Answer (score 2):

Thredded maintainer here.

What version of the Gem are you using, by the way?

For the time being, if you haven't solidified how you would like your users' roles to be defined, I would consider making that method as simple as possible. For example - if the current user has an `id` of ... 4? or 5? Or whatever your personal user record id is - return true. Otherwise false.

Ask your user object if they are you! :)

```
def admin
  self.name == 'Joel'
end
```

If the current user record has my name - then yes, I am an admin.

If there's anything I can do to help, please feel free to head over to the issues and open up a ticket. We'd be more than happy to help.

Comment: hi , thank you for reply.. we're currently configuring our database to integrate user names and roles.. for the mean time i will just use what you suggested.. , we will just open a ticket if we have question...thanks again